# Can every function be represented as polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functions, field-theory

Can every function $f: R^n \to R^n$ or$R^n \to R$ be represented as polynomial either of degree $n$ or infinite degree. Are there any proofs to  this statement if it is true?If it has no Taylor-Power Series that does not necessary mean that there is no polynomial to represent the function.

Comment: It is not clear what you man by infinite degree or by represented as. Any polynomial is unbounded, so most likely cannot represent a bounded function.

Comment: If your function is a smooth it can be represented by a polynomial.  It it is discontinuous, then maybe with some degree of error around the discontinuities.  If it is nowhere continuous, then no.

Comment: "Infinite degree" is dodgy. Lot's of functions can be represented by a Taylor series which is sort of an infinite polynomial but even those aren't necessarily defined/converge for all points and (everywhere) discontinuous functions like the characteristic function on the rationals, $\chi_{\mathbb Q}$, hasn't got one in a classical point wise convergent sense.

Comment: Weierstrass' theorem allows you to approximate arbitrary continuous functions by polynomials, at least on compact sets. The subtlety is that the lower degree coefficients in general cannot stay the same through the sequence. For instance there is no power series approximation of $1/(1+x^2) $ on $[-2,2] $ but it can still be approximated by polynomials there. Note that this is a perfectly nice smooth function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polynomials aka algebraic functions are countable, were as every function is uncountable ( actually $\aleph_2$ is the cardinality of every function)

Comment: The set of all polynomials with real coefficients has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, namely $\beth_1$. The set of *all* real-valued functions with real coefficients has cardinality $\beth_2$ (which need not be $\aleph_2$!). But the set of continuous functions has cardinality $\beth_1$ again. So the question of approximation of continuous functions or piecewise continuous functions by polynomials is reasonable.

Comment: @Ian : Thank you! Learned something new

Comment: Sorry, I said something wrong: the set of all real-valued functions of a real variable has cardinality $\beth_2$. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong. [Weierstraß function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is a counter example:

> the function was defined as the sum of a Fourier series:
>   $$
>     f(x)=\sum_{n=0} ^\infty a^n \cos(b^n \pi x),
> $$
>   where $0<a<1, b$ is a positive odd integer, and
>   $
>     ab > 1+\frac{3}{2} \pi. $

Since it is not differrentiable, there is no Taylor Expansion. Here's a gif:

$\hskip2.7in$[image]

Comment: HAving no taylor series mean it cannot be represented as a polynomial?The coefficients doesnt  have to be the same as the taylor series

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis I just wanted to oppose the impression that everything is expressable with an "infinite degree", i.e. Taylor expansion...

Comment: Oh so You cant answer if every function has a polynomial expression or not?Just about the taylor series

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x)$ is zero for $x<0.5$ and one otherwise. Write $f$ as a Taylor series $f(x)=\sum a_ix^i$. Considering $f(0)=0$ tells us $a_0=0$. You can differentiate Taylor series term by term. Considering $f'(0)=0$ tells us $a_1=0$. And so on, showing that all of the $a_i=0$. That means $f(x)$ is identically zero. So the series doesn't in fact represent $f$. So no such representation of $f$ exists.